# Passing Routeing related props to component not rendered by <Route>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

i have a Dashboard Component:

```
class DashboardPage extends Component {
  ....

  render() {
    const currentLocationPath = this.props.location.pathname;
    const isAuthenticated = true;

    // redirecting to /dashboard/main and saving current state to next path by pushing it to history object
    if (currentLocationPath === '/dashboard/' || currentLocationPath === '/dashboard') {
      this.props.history.push('/dashboard/main');
    }
    const { match } = this.props;

    if (isAuthenticated) {
      return (
        <div className="DashboardPage d-flex flex-column flex-grow">

          {/* email confirmation message for loggedin user to verify email ID*/}
          {!this.state.isEmailVerified ? <div className="email-confirmation">
            <span className="email-confirmation__desktop">
              Please check your inbox to confirm your email <strong>{'loggedin user\'s email'}</strong>.
            Didn’t receive an email? </span>
            <span className="email-confirmation__mobile">Confirm your email. </span>
            <a className="js-resend-email" href="#" onClick={this.resendMail}>Resend</a>
          </div> : null}

          <div className="DasboardPageMain d-flex flex-grow">

            {/* sidebar with slide-in effect from left on toggle */}

            <SidebarMenu currentLocationPath={currentLocationPath} channels={this.state.channels} />

            <div className="DashboardPage__overlay" />

            <main className="DashboardPage__Content d-flex flex-grow">
              {/* swapping DashboardPage's Child Components based on current url set by <Router/> */}
              <Route path="/dashboard/main" render={() => <Dashboard toggleModal={this.toggleModal} />} />
              <Route path="/dashboard/channels/:id/:channelName" component={VideoStats} />
              <Route path="/dashboard/edit_video" component={EditVideo} />
              <Route path="/dashboard/account" component={Account} />
              <Route path="/dashboard/socialMedia" component={SocialMedia} />
              <Route path="/dashboard/media-library" component={MediaLibrary} />
              <Route path="/dashboard/shares" component={Shares} />
              {/* <Route path="/dashboard/platform/:data"  component={Platforms} /> */}
              {/* <Route exact path="/dashboard/channels/:id/:channelName" component={VideosList} /> */}

            </main>

            {/* Modal With Nested Form to add Chaanel's info. */}
            <Modal className="addChannelModal" isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggleModal} >
              <ModalBody>
                <AddChannelForm toggleModal={this.toggleModal} notifySuccess={this.notifySuccess} notifyError={this.notifyError} />
              </ModalBody>
            </Modal>
          </div>
          <Footer />

          {/* React toastify for toast notifications */}
          <ToastContainer
            className={{ textAlign: 'center' }}
            progressClassName={css({ background: '#007aff' })} />
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return <Redirect to={'/'} />;
    }
  }
}

export default withRouter(DashboardPage);
```

Now i want to access the router url params inside `<SidebarMenu>` component but inside `<SidebarMenu>` console.log(this.props.match.params) is showing empty object.

But if i do console.log(this.props.match.params) inside any of components being rendered by `<Route/>` for example:

```
<Route path="/dashboard/account" component={Account} />
```

I easily get all params in url.

Is there way to access all these router related props in `<SidebarMenu>`
?

currently i am conditionally rendering JSX inside `<SidebarMenu>` like so:

```
const currentLocationPath = this.props.currentLocationPath;
const pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');

          { pathArray.length > 3 &&
            <Media tag="li" className={`${pathArray.length === 3 ? 'li-active' : null} li-channels align-items-center mb-1 py-1`}>
              {/* Chevron Icon */}
              <Media left middle tag="span" className="media-chevron-right ml-5 mr-1">
                <FontAwesomeIcon size="xs" icon={currentLocationPath == '/dashboard/main' ? faChevronRight : faChevronDown} className="" />
              </Media>

              {/* channel's main body */}
              <Media body className="text-center text-sm-left mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                <Media heading tag="h6" className="m-0">
                  Channels
                </Media>
              </Media>
            </Media> }
```

Comment: is your `DashboardPage ` is enclosed inside `<Router>`?

Comment: yes. 
`ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
      <Route path="/verify/email/:token" component={HomePage} />
      <Route path="/reset/password/:token" component={HomePage} />
      <Route path="/dashboard" component={DashboardPage} />
      {/* <Route path="/video" component={VideoPage} /> */}
      <Route component={HomePage} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

registerServiceWorker();`

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing `match` to `<SidebarMenu>` inside `<DashboardPage>` render.

You could either pass it as a prop inside your DashboardPage render:

```
<SidebarMenu match={match} currentLocationPath={currentLocationPath} channels={this.state.channels} />
```

Or wrap it with `withRouter`.

Comment: i have tried both but still doesn't work. i am getting routing related props within components rendered by `<Route />` component which is what i also need to access to inside `<Sidebar />` component.

Comment: Basically my concern is that is it even possible to have access to or a way to pass all the routing props such as match, history etc. inside a component not being rendered by `<Route />` component ?

Comment: As far as I know ```withRouter``` is there for this reason. If it's not receiving the props than I would check the ```SidebarMenu```, why it's not receiving props.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `props` like this in component

```
<Route path="/dashboard/account" render={ (props) => <Account {...props} /> }/>
```